# TCPDF scaling and quality issue

Tags: tcpdf

I am generating PDF from image stream but there is always a little difference in the size of actual image and the image scales down as well .

I am using TCPDF class for it

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Set up your image document at a resolution of 72dpi and the document size of A4 (or whatever size you set in tcpdf).

Then when you call `$tcpdf->image('/path/to/image.ext')` the image should be the correct size.

Think in **points** - pixels aren't much use in a tcpdf-generated pdf space.