# Outdated TCPDF for use with quality images

Tags: image, laravel-5.4, tcpdf

I have been looking for ways to improve the quality of images with TCPDF since I need a quite high resolution, but the answers I find are from 5 years ago. many of the answers point to SetJPEGQuality () and setImageScale () but these do not even appear in the documentation now and no changes are made when implementing them.

The generate documents are medical reports, so changing the format of images from one type to another is unthinkable because users do not understand formats, although the quality of the images is optimal jpg of more than 10M, but when the pdf is generated, always presents a blur in them.

The system use a Laravel 5.4 flavor, and "elibyy/tcpdf-laravel 5.4" package

```
            $pdf->setJPEGQuality(100);
            $pdf->setImageScale(1.53);
            $pdf->Image(public_path() . "/img/histo/" . $data->images[0]->image_url, 140, 82, 65, 55, '', '', '', true, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

What do you recommend to improve quality, or should you migrate to another library and if so, to which?

Thank you

Comment: Please include the code you're using.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448571/tcpdf-image-quality-issues?rq=1 ?

Comment: Veve Thanks, Yes, I been using the methods in that answer, but there are no changes in the code so far!!

Comment: There are multiples answers in the linked question. Did you try them all?

Comment: Veve, the only one Im clueless about is FPDI library.

Comment: FPDI is an extension of TCPDF, it's really easy to use. Look at their site.